# C++ detached thread continues to work after its associated object was deleted

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a scope I create an object, which contains a thread. The thread is detached in object c-tor. Finally I delete the object, but the thread keeps continuing, after the associated object memory was freed. Does the detached thread saves the objects copy or it only reference to the program stack, which will be erased further on?

```
struct test_detach {
    test_detach()
    : thr_(&test_detach::loop, this) {
        thr_.detach();
    }

    void loop() {
        while(true) {
            cout << "loop test" << endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }
    }

    std::thread thr_;
};

int main()
{
    {
        test_detach *test = new test_detach;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        delete test;
    }
    cout << "Sleep" << endl;;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    cout << "Finish!" << endl;;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output:

```
loop test
loop test
Sleep
loop test
loop test
loop test
loop test
loop test
loop test
Finish!
```

Comment: You should declare member functions that don't access *any* class members as **static**.  Which now also provides insight in why the thread can just keep motoring and doesn't care that you deleted the object.  The notion that a thread will stop automagically is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the thread keeps on going until the program is terminated. Your thread doesn't use any data fields of the particular `test_detach` structure, so there is no SEGFAULT. If you however add a member variable to the structure and attempt to access it from the detached thread after the structure was `delete`d from the main thread it might cause a SEGFAULT / undefined behaviour etc. The `test_detach` structure is located on the heap. It is not copied anywhere, that is sort of the point. However:

```
void loop() {
   int x = 0;
    while(true) {
        cout << "loop test, x: " << x++ << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
```

will work correctly since x is on the stack which is maintained for the particular thread.

Comment: Well, I observed similar behaviour using test_detached object in stack and in heap (as in code above). So, the point is **not** to engaged class members, which were to be deleted, after the object memory was freed. Thanks!